# How do I display data from cURL into a table in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I need to get data from a website and display in a table in my website.  I am getting the data correctly but now just need to add it to a table so that it is more legible.

This is the code for some of the information I am getting:

```
echo "<div style='font-weight: bold;'>getProvinces</div>";

$args = array();
$args["strSessionId"] = $session;

$result = CurlFunction($args, "getProvinces");
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

And

```
case "getProvinces":
    {
        $Url = "https://apitest.axxess.co.za/" . 
"calls/rsapi/getProvinces.json";
        $curl->setBasicAuthentication($Username, $Password);
        $curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,2);
        $curl->get($Url, $d);

        break;
    }
```

I just need some help on how to get the above info into a table.  And if possible only sections.  I have attached an image to show what I am getting at the moment as well as which data I would like to have in a Table format.

Thanks[image: example]

Link to complete code I am using: https://transfernow.net/923hx9h1f2er

Comment: HINT: i think u need to use json_decode then you can use loop in your html

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is I don't know how to that in this scenario?

Comment: check answer, i hope this will help u

Comment: is your issue resolved ??

Comment: No, unfortunately not yet.  Still trying to get it resolved.

Comment: what issue are you getting?

Comment: Can't get it to display in tables -- Only relevant information as per screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode` to obtain an array representing your response data, and use a `foreach` loop to create key-value pairs inside a table for each data item.

The code could look like:

```php
$jsoned = json_decode($result, true)
?>
<table>
<?php foreach ($jsoned as $k => $v) {?>
<tr><td> <?=$k?> </td><td> <?=$v?> </td></tr>
<?php } ?>
```

btw, `<?= $var ?>` is a shortcut for `<? echo $var; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, convert your `json` response into an array by using [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) like:

```
// assuming `$jsonResponse` is your json response variable
$decoded = json_decode($jsonResponse,true); // here true will use return response in array format
```

Then, you can use your response check like:

```
if($decoded['intCode'] == 200){
    print_r($decoded['arrProvinceId']); // this will return you your response in array
}
```

now, you can you [`foreach()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop with `html` whatever you need with `$decoded['arrProvinceId']` result.

Comment: error with `undefined variable jsonResponse`  am not sure where to find that variable.

Comment: @KeithKing: amazing, where you save your json response? any variable? share your complete code of `CurlFunction` method

Comment: `jsonResponse` is just a sample name... @KeithKing

Comment: its an API i am using so I am calling the json from the website to display in my webpage.  here is the path `https://apitest.example.co.za/" . "calls/rsapi/getProvinces.json`

Comment: @KeithKing: share your code which you have inside this method `CurlFunction()`